# Strange behavior for date field in Experience cloud

Tags: lightning-web-components, experience-cloud, formatting, date-field

In a date field displayed in Experience Cloud, if the date is mm/dd/yyyy, and I manually enter 14/01/2024, it will display as 02/01/2025 when I click outside the date field.

```
<lightning-input name="ExpirationDate" label="Expiration Date" type="Date" value={product.values.ExpirationDate}
    onchange={handleInput}></lightning-input>
```

Internally, on the same field, it shows this error:
[image]

How do I enforce this check that is happening internally on my experience page (LWC)